# How to program the Sudoku game logic in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sudoku

I am trying to make a Sudoku game in Unity3D but I'm currently stuck on the logic behind the game. (*checking if all the numbers in the same subgrid, row and column are different*)

I have been able to get a script that generates the whole grid running, both for a 2x2, 2x3 and a 3x3 level. The part that I am stuck on is making the 2D Array to hold the selected values for all subgrids. I can also provide the full GenerateGrid script if it's needed, but any help apart from that would be of help.

(**Note:** *I have tried my best to research as much as I can about this, but none of the stuff I found online was about a Unity3D version of the game, only 2D ones*)

***Thanks!***

Comment: So, what is your question about ? Understanding the multidimensional arrays or will you an insight about your logic ? You generate the gris, ok, and now you are wondering how to check if the grid has been solved is it ?

Comment: Hey, Thomas! Yes, I am wondering how to actually make the code check if the subgrid, column and row of the selected tile is correct. (no repeating numbers) I have tried comparing each tile in the subgrid to each other tile, but to no success.

Comment: The Close votes are way off. This post was not, in any way, asking for a recommendation for a book or a tool. It's asking for an algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? The board is a 9x9 grid. Skip the multidimensional syntax as it just complicates things (in my opinion).

(Pseudocode - I haven't tried compiling this.)

```
int[] board = new int[9*9]; 

/// note that coordinates are zero-based. So, rows, columns. etc. go from 0..8, not 1..9

int getCell(int x, int y)
{
   return board[y * 9 + x];
}

bool colIsValid(int x)
{
   var digitsFound = new bool[9];

   for(int y=0; y < 9; ++y)
   {
      var cellValue = getCell(x,y);
    
      if (cellValue > 0)
      {
         if (digitsFound[cellValue])
            return false;
         digits[cellValue] = true;
      }
       
   }
   return true;
}

bool rowIsValid(int y)
{
   var digitsFound = new bool[9];

   for(int x=0; x < 9; ++x)
   {
      var cellValue = getCell(x,y);
    
      if (cellValue > 0)
      {
         if (digitsFound[cellValue])
            return false;
         digits[cellValue] = true;
      }
       
   }

   return true;
}

// determine if the 3x3 subgrid containing cell (x,y) is valid.
bool subGridIsValid(int cellX, int cellY)
{
    var minX = (cellX / 3) * 3;
    var maxX = minX + 3;
    var minY = (cellY / 3) * 3;
    var maxY = minY + 3;

    var digitsFound = new bool[9];
    for(var j=minY; j < maxY; ++j)
    {
        for(var i = minX; i < maxX; ++i)
        {
            var cellValue = getCell(i,j);
            if (cellValue > 0)
            {
                if (digitsFound[cellValue])
                    return false;
                digitsFound[cellValue] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I shall try this later and let you know if it did compile or not. Keep in mind that every time the user selects a value and inputs it into the specific subgrid, it'd run that whole script. Would that be optimized and do you think it'd work correctly, in order to be able to outline the error (if there is an error) that the user made. (the number repeating in the subgrid, row or column)

Comment: Also, since my levels (Easy, Medium and Hard) are divided in 2x2, 2x3 and 3x3 grids, would there be any way to let the code know which level has been selected and change the sizes of the grids accordingly, without the need for me to rewrite that code 2 more times for the Easy and Medium levels?

Comment: @PaperMag For your second question: Just replace all the `9`s with the width of the supergrid, and the `3`s with the width of the subgrid. You could easily make that configurable. For optimization, you could run all three validity tests (row, column, subgrid) simultaneously. In any case, for a normal Sudoku grid with 81 cells, this isn't a TON of operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent yourself a Sudoku as a grid (with rows and columns). Each grid cell is itself a subgrid (with sub-rows and sub-columns)

To check if the user solved the Sudoku you have 3 conditions

- there is no duplicate number in a subgrid itself
- there is no duplicate number in a same sub-row for every cell on the same row
- there is no duplicate number in a same sub-column for every cell on the same column

From there we can begin to work. I would recommend to use two sets of bidimensionnal arrays. One for the main grid and a second for each sub-grids
So basically...your grid declaration may looks like this `int[,][,] sudoku` and sudoku[1,2][3,4] will access the row 1, column 2, sub-row 3, sub-column 4 if that makes sense

So to check game conditions:

- test every sub-cells of `sudoku[1,2][i,j]` to make sure there is no duplicated numbers in the grid cell [1,2]
- test every sub-cells for `sudoku[1,i][2,j]` to make sure there is no duplicated number in the sub-column 2 of the column 1
- test every sub-cells for `sudoku[i,1][j,2]` to make sure there is no duplicated number in the sub-row 2 of the row 1

You should find a better optimisation to check the grid rather than brute force it sub-cell by sub-cell but I leave it up to you.

Hope that helped ;)

Comment: Hey, Thomas! That's actually exactly what I did at first, but I found that it is really unoptimized, since Unity3D listens for changes in the values 60 times each second. Therefore, the 9x9 grid in Hard mode would be hellish when it comes to the performance. (Every tile comparing itself to every other tile in the specific subgrid, column and row)

Comment: You surely don't want to test the entire grid in an update method. maybe when the grid is fulfiled and on user input. This is another problem

Comment: Yes! My idea is to update the grid every time the user inputs a number into it and to run the check whenever that happens. Any idea on how to get it to work? OnClick event maybe?